# Why do the child widgets of my custom UITableViewCell stack on top of each other?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that I've designed in a storyboard. The custom cell contains a label and a text field. The label should be on the left side of the cell and the text field should be on the right side. But no matter what combination of constraints I try (constraining the right side of the text field to the right side of the cell, spacing the left side of the text field 300 pixels from the label, etc...) the text field always ends up stacked on the label when I run my app.

Here's a screenshot of a portion of the storyboard

[image]

In this image, the trailing edge of the text field is set to the trailing margin of its parent.

This is what it looks like in the app.

[image]

This is my code for the custom table cell class:

```
class ItemRowCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var itemDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var quantity: UITextField!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the UI debugger?

Comment: UI Debugger shows that neither widget has the constraint tying them to the edge of the cell and the leading value for the text field is set to the leading value of the label.

Answer (score 0):

You've set something incorrectly... I suggest, start fresh.

Delete the current Label and Text Field.

Add a new label to your cell prototype, and set the Leading Constraint to 0 and the Vertical Constraint to Centered - should look like this:

[image]

Add a new Text Field, and set the Trailing Constraint to 0, the Vertical Constraint to Centered, and the Width Constraint to 80:

[image]

Re-connect your @IBOutlets, and run the app.

Comment: show a screen cap of your constraints? If you followed that, you should have gotten different results.

Comment: Well, that's quite odd... Looks the same as mine, but my label and text field lay out just as they should... Not doing anything in code that could effect the cell elements?

Comment: I'm assuming there aren't any size class differences?

Comment: @robz - set the background color of your label to red... set the width of your textfield to 200... see what results. I'm wondering if you're editing the wrong object?